# Get days of week for date range, javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have date range

```
var fromDate = "2017-01-05";
var toDate = "2017-01-10";
```

How can I get days of the week that belong to that range?

A range can be different, it can be 2016-12-25 to 2017-05-05, etc. I need to return unique days of the week from provided date range.

The result should be an array of days of weeks. For first range should be `["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"]`

Moment can be used if needed, but no jQuery.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/snoopy_15/fata6ocb/ but I don't like my solution and of course, it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution:

1. [Get all dates from the range](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/7905510).
2. Loop through the result of step one and return the days of the week:

   ```
   var dates = [...]; //(step one result)
   let weekdays = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
       weekdays.push(moment(dates[i]).day())
   }
   ```
3. Make an array of weekdays:

   ```
   var wkDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
   ```
4. Get the day names:

   ```
   let weekdaysNamesRange = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < wkDays.length; j++) {
           if (weekdays[i] === j) {
              weekdaysNamesRange.push(wkDays[j]);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
5. Get unique days:

   ```
   var unique = weekdaysNamesRange.filter((item, index, ar) => {
       return weekdaysNamesRange.indexOf(item) === index;
   });
   ```

I guess there is a better solution, but this is all I came up with.

Comment: For some reason, a code isn't formatted, not sure why.

Comment: You have to indent the code by additional 4 spaces in enumerations.